# How to disable automatic shutdown - Critical temperature reached (97 C)

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04

I have a samsung laptop with a i3 processor and 4GB of RAM. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I have seen various trouble shooting guides for acpi, however I cant find clear information on how to disable the automatic shutdown when the critical temperature has been reached or how to increase it.

I am trying to compile android's kernel and it utilises processing power that takes the temperature up to the maximum acpi value of 97 degrees then the system shuts down without warning.

This is HIGHLY annoying and it caused me to lose work. I would at least expect a warning and some kind of human intervention option to prevent this from happening.

Any help/suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not disable it, or you CPU could burn.

You possibly need better ventilation / cooling of the PC.

Other related answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/57571/where-can-i-control-the-critical-temperature-for-a-system-shutdown

You should be able to enable/disable/modify HD smart attributes using [smartcl](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartctl.8.html) command.

Try as root:
smartctl /dev/sda -A

To disable SMART management:
smartctl /dev/sda -s off

Hopefully this will disable temperature triggered shut down. I didn't find a way to change the temperature parameter.

Comment: i know that it (disable the automatic shutdown) is harmful for my CPU.But can i increase the critical temperature value. if yes,then how  to increase it.

Answer (score 0):

I see this question all the time, and instead of getting it answered, the usual responses are to clean the fan or warnings not to disable it. I have this issue and can't access the inside of my laptop for cleaning.

from the research i've done, if you can access your 'system cooling policy' and change it from 'active' to 'passive', this will increase the temp your processor has to reach before shutting down, like from 120 to 160, critical is 200. I am unable to access this on my windows 7 laptop, but some laptops you can:

control panel/power options/ change plan settings/ change advance power settings / change settings currently unavailable/ system cooling policy/

and change the dropdown from active to passive.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your computer should never reach that temperature if used 100%. Only if you are overclocking or have inadequate cooling should you reach that.

I have seen it on 2 of my systems:

- One had missing thermal paste. When that was added it worked fine.
- One had the fan blocked (placed on fabric).

I used the first system for quite some time before figuring out the missing thermal paste. What I did was adjusting the CPU speed.

In my case the CPU was an i7 (quad core with hyperthreading). I found out that if I just lowered the speed of CPU 4 (core 6+7) then that was actually sufficient:

```
sudo cpufreq-set -c 6 -f 1.2GHz
sudo cpufreq-set -c 7 -f 1.2GHz
```

The other cores could run at full speed.

So my advice is:

- Find something that will trigger the heating issue fast (my case: 8 bzip2's in parallel for 5 minutes. burnP6 will probably work too). Monitor temperature with `watch sensors`
- Note if one core is consistently hotter than other cores.
- Lower the frequency of the hottest cores (`cpufreq-info` will tell you what frequencies are supported). If your cpu uses hyperthreading: CPU 0 = core 0+1.
- Continue to do so until the temperature of all cores stay well below the critical limit.